# Spreadsheet style enter in vim?

Tags: vim, insert

Here is my data:

```
1.333840,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1.xxxxxx,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1.yyyyyy,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1.zzzzzz,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

What I would like to do is have Vim remember the location of the column where i inserted.  This would be handy in handling fixed entry tables like the one I have above.  I desire to stay in <s>insert</s> **REPLACE** mode but minimize the use of the cursor, overwriting template data like above.

xxxxxx should be 444444
yyyyyy should be 555555
zzzzzz should be 666666

What I would want to do is start at Row 1 Column Position 3 and type
`i444444<spreadsheetenter>555555<spreadsheetenter>666666<esc>`

Is there a special mode or key binding that would help me do this?  Basically keep the return at the same fixed column from when I re-enter into insert mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- if you want to "overwrite" the template data, you don't want to do it in INSERT mode, you need replace mode. by pressing `R`
- many vim magics are done in NORMAL mode, you should think about it.

For example, for your problem, I would:

- cursor(`*`) at `*333840`, press `R`, start overwriting
- when finish, press `<ESC>jbR`, your cursor will go to `*xxxxxx`, and ready to replace

you could create a mapping for this kind of job, like:

```
inoremap <leader>g <esc>jbR
```

it works like:

[image]

Comment: What did you make the gif in?

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right about using replace mode, I think you got the essence of what I'm looking for. Also, like @FDinoff I'd like to know how you created the awesome gif!

Comment: This looks like it's made with [Byzanz](http://handytutorial.com/install-byzanz-and-record-animated-gifs-in-ubuntu-12-0412-1011-10/).

Comment: @FDinoff it is byzanz

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following mappings for your `<spreadsheetenter>`:

```
:nnoremap <S-CR> g`[j
:inoremap <S-CR> <Esc>g`[jR
```

### Bonus

And here's a more complex insert mode variant that keeps the mode (insert vs. (virtual-) replace):

```
function! s:GetCurrentInsertMode()
    let s:currentInsertMode = mode()
    return ''
endfunction
function! s:RestartCurrentInsertMode()
    if s:currentInsertMode ==# 'i'
        startinsert
    elseif s:currentInsertMode ==# 'R'
        startreplace
    elseif s:currentInsertMode ==# 'Rv'
        startgreplace
    else
        throw 'ASSERT: Unknown mode: ' . string(s:currentInsertMode)
    endif
endfunction
inoremap <silent> <expr> <SID>(GetCurrentInsertMode) <SID>GetCurrentInsertMode()
inoremap <silent> <script> <S-CR> <SID>(GetCurrentInsertMode)<C-\><C-n>g`[j:call <SID>RestartCurrentInsertMode()<CR>
```

Comment: This is more purely achieving the goal of the question...  Nice use of `\`[`, first time learning of it.  I saw in the documentation "`\`[` - To the first character of the previously changed or yanked text." Is this underdefined? Because it seems that `\`[` marks where insert position begins even if no text is altered.

Comment: Well, entering insert mode (even when not entering anything) is considered a change.

Comment: For learning purposes, is this the utility of virtual replace: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76968/what-is-the-point-of-virtual-replace-mode-in-vim ? Just trying to see what the inherent value is, and if it applies in my scenario.

Comment: The difference is with multi-width characters like Tab.

Answer (score 1):

Try the csv plugin. It does this by default in (Virtual)Replace mode.

Comment: I tried this and at the first <enter> it goes into insert mode.

Comment: Please try again with the latest version. There was a small bug with previous commits. If it still doesn't work for you, I suggest you open a new issue.